# Calling function sequentially in vuejs

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I am having some problem in vuejs in executing a function/method sequentially.
I have three functions like:

```
MethodA: function(){
    if(x = 1){
        value1 = 2;
    }

    if (x ==2){
         value2 = 4;
    }

    this.MethodB();
}

MethodB: function(){
    Total value = value1 + value2;
}

MethodC: function (){
    this.$http.get('api/getvalue').then(function(response){
        this.set('somedata', response.data);

        response.data.forEach(para){
            if(para.id == 1){
                this.MethodA();
            }
            if(para.id == 2){
                this.MethodA();
            }
        }
    });
}

ready: function(){
    this.MethodC();
}
```

I would like to execute `this.MethodB()` only after `MethodC` and `MethodA` has completely executed. How can I do this?

Comment: I edited your question writing `MethodC` but now I'm not sure what you meant. Could you please explain how do you expect to have any `Method` to execute before/after the others if they are circularly dependent on each other?

Comment: I'd use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise) with `.then` to chain the calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Javascript Promises with Vue.js methods:

```
methodA: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       //run all your methodA code here
       ...

       resolve('MethodA finished');
    });
},
methodB: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       //run all your methodB code here
       ...

       resolve('MethodB finished');
    });
},
methodC: function() {
    //run your methodC code
}
```

Now, to run methodC only when methodA and methodB are finished, you can use the promises `.then` and chain them together. For ex:

```
ready: function() {
    //save `this` to a variable just to make it easier to be accessed within the chain
    let self = this;

    //run methodA, then methodB...only then, methodC
    self.methodA.then(function(resultA) {
        console.log(resultA);
        return self.methodB();
    }).then(function(resultB) {
        console.log(resultB);
        self.methodC();
    });
}
```

Note: if you running AJAX calls within methodA or methodB, make sure to resolve the promise only when you receive a response. In your ex.:

```
this.$http.get('api/getvalue').then(function(response){ 
    ...
    resolve('My method is now complete'); 
}
```

Comment: @TashiTobgay You are welcome :) Javascript promises are great for async code control.